# Keras model saved in ModelCheckpoint in tensorflow can't be loaded on another machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have 2 windows machine (A and B) both have tensorflow-gpu 1.10 installed.

I have a training.py which train and save the best full model

```
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(params['filepath_best'], monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=params['log_dir'])]
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='MSE', metrics=['MSE'])
history = model.fit(keras_input_fn(filenames=training_files, mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN).batch(16).repeat(1000), 
                    epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=625, 
                    validation_data=keras_input_fn(filenames=training_files, mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL).batch(16).repeat(1000), 
                    validation_steps=625, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

I also have a detect.py which load the trained model and do predictions

```
model = load_model(params['filepath_best'])
```

training.py and detect.py runs separately. training runs fine, and detect.py in machine A can load the model generated by the training.py on machine A. However, detect.py in machine A can NOT load the copied model generated by the training.py on machine B. In the same way, detect.py in machine B can only load the model generated from machine B, it can't load a copied model generated from machine A. the training.py and detect.py in both machines are identical but the dir is different. It seems that the saved model contains the info of local dir of the specific machine which generates the model thus it can't be used on another machine. The copied model is in the correct dir for loading.

In training.py, I have a function relu_advanced(x) which basically truncate the maximum to 255, and it is called when construct the keras model.

```
def relu_advanced(x):
    return K.relu(x, max_value=255) 

# in model construction part
net = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(function = relu_advanced)(net)
```

When I run detec.py on machine B using copied model from machine A, it complains the relu_advanced function using the dir of training.py on machine A.

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 712, in call
return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
File "D:/dir_on_machine_A/training.py", line 391, in relu_advanced
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

If I put training.py on the same dir on machine B as if on machine A, the detect.py terminated just after the load_model() without giving any error message.

My question is how can I copy a trained model generated by ModelCheckpoint on one machine to another and load it from another machine using tensorflow and keras? Thanks!

Comment: you mean to say, the saved weight file obtained from save checkpoint when copied over to other machine couldn't be loaded?

Comment: The settings of ModelCheckpoint only output the full model, no separate weight file. When load_model, it complains a line of training.py with the different dir of the machine where the model generated. Something like

    File "D:/dir_on_machine_A/training.py", line 391, in relu_advanced
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation

If I put training.py in the same dir on machine B as if on machine A, it will terminate just after load_model() without any error message.